# Calling methods from Xcode Debugger?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, debugging

what's the correct way to call a method from the Xcode debugger command line ?

For example if I'm inside the sort: method of my class A (using the debugger), how can I call debugSort: method that belongs to class A too ?

( My code is Objective-C btw )

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> To call an Objective-C method in the gdb console, you have to cast the return type (since gdb doesn't really know what the return value is):

**`(gdb) call (void)[textField setStringValue: @"Bork"]`**

—[Quickies for gdb](http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=gdb)

Comment: You can also use `print` or `po`. The latter will send the return value (which must be an object) a `debugDescription` message and print the string that that message returns. In practice, this means `po` prints the object—which is what its name means.