# call method on view from Xcode debugger

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

Suppose I select a UIView from the "debug view hierarchy" in the Xcode debugger. I can print its description; it looks something like this:

```
Printing description of $17:
<MyView: 0x7fc6a451c030; frame = (0 0; 375 270); layer = <CALayer: 0x608000029700>>
```

That's nice, but what I really want to do is call [myView myMethod] and print the result. In this particular case, myMethod returns an NSString, but I imagine that won't always be true.

I've read [Calling methods from Xcode Debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915453/calling-methods-from-xcode-debugger), but it does not appear to help for my case, because myView is not self.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can set the language to Swift in LLDB (the console)

  ```
  (lldb) settings set target.language swift
  ```
- Add a breakPoint in the class where `MyView` belongs, and in a scope where you're sure that is it is already instantiated.
- Launch the app, and when the breakpoint is reached:
- type `po` (*print object*) followed by the name of your view

  ```
  (lldb) po $myView
  ```

if you want more details use `p` (short for *print*): `(lldb) p myView`

- Call your method on the view preceded by `e` or `expr`(short for `expression`) :

  ```
  (lldb) expr $myView.myMethod()
  ```
- To see changes in the UI call this

  ```
  (lldb) expr CATransaction.flush()
  ```

For more, [here](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html) is the reference for lldb commands.

---

You could also use the memory address, given after printing the description of your UI element, and cast that to a usable type:

```
(lldb) expr -- import UIKit
(lldb) expr -- let $myView = unsafeBitCast(0x7fc6a451c030, to: MyView.self)
(lldb) expr $myView.myMethod()
//Or if you'd like to create a variable with that result:
(lldb) expr let $string = $myView.myMethod()
(lldb) po $string
```

Comment: Your answer implies that having the view as `$1` or the like is not enough to call a method on it. Is that correct?

Comment: @WilliamJockusch If you print that object again the `$x` is going to change, so my belief is no, But, I've included in the answer a way to use the address given by the description.