# call methods on WKWebView from lldb

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, lldb

As I debug my app to find why the webview dowsn't receive my messages, I found out that another WkWebview (let's call it B) was created on top of my existing webview (A). Since I only have reference to A, I'm trying to evaluate js directly on B using it's memory address. 
what is the correct way to do that in lldb?

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52573575/call-method-on-view-from-xcode-debugger), I've tried:
`settings set target.language swift`
`e -- import WKWebview`
`e -- let $webView = unsafeBitCast(0x13299e400, to:WKWebview.self)`

in order to call webView.evaluateJavaScript,
but lldb says:

````
let $webView = unsafeBitCast(0x13299e400, to:WKWebview.self)
               ^

error: <EXPR>:3:46: error: cannot convert value of type 'module<WKWebview>' to expected argument type 'U.Type'
let $webView = unsafeBitCast(0x13299e400, to:WKWebview.self)```
````

Comment: It might be easier to achieve this by switching to objective-c mode of lldb like this:
`e -l objc -- [0x13299e400 evaluateJavaScript:@"your javascript code" completionHandler:nil]`

Comment: @Kamil.S I had to make a few adjustments but it does seem to work. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: please post your final solution as an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kamil.S I managed to get it right.
The complete steps were:

```
(lldb) e @import <WKWebview.h>
(lldb) e NSString *$js = <my javascript to evaluate>
(lldb) e (void)[(id)0x10504ea00 evaluateJavaScript:$js completionHandler:nil]
```